# Creation of polar series with mixed data type

Tags: python-polars

I am using '0.18.3' polars version and trying to create below series:

`x = pl.Series(["1",2,"3"] )` 
`print(x)

shape: (3,)
Series: '' [str]
[
"1"
**null**
"3"
]`

I dont have any expected o/p  in mind, but with this o/p it was not clear whether it a really value is missing or it is issue with data type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a series or a column in a DataFrame which has mixed data types. That's simply a hard constraint on arrow memory.

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> it was not clear whether it a really value is missing or it is issue with data type.

Are you wondering if there's a way to tell the difference between these two Series:

```
pl.Series(["1",2,"3"])

pl.Series(["1",None,"3"])
```

If that's what you're asking then no there isn't a way other than with the underlying python lists. There aren't multiple nulls where one is for truly missing data and another for data which is the wrong dtype.

Comment: let suppose i am reading a csv file and in one column of csv file, all values are string except 5 values. these 5 values are int in nature.

in dataframe, these will come as a null value. as a user how would I know, if it data is actually missing in csv file or it is an dtype issue.

coming from pandas background, i assumed that data is missing and i dropped these rows, which impacted my analysis. @Dean-MacGregor

Comment: You do see that that is a completely different scenario from your question don't you?

Comment: I think it's a same thing. From the o/p of my question, I really dont now null is coming due to real missing value or dtype issue, if i dont know my i/p

Comment: It's not though.  When you run `pl.read_csv` polars parses everything in the csv. When you initialize a Series with `pl.Series(["1", 2, "3"])` then python is first parsing each value and determines their data type before polars sees them. In the former case, polars can change its parsing behavior to accommodate some malformations. In the latter case, it's already had the parsing done, so it can't.